# Search for two specific elements in multidimensional vectors

Tags: c++, vector

Consider the following vector

```
vector<vector<string>> a_words(80000,vector<string>(3));
```

which is a three dimension vector;

Now consider the following elements:

```
  Joan Williams 30
  Mike Williams 40
  Joan Smith 30
  William Anderson 20
  Sara Jon 33
```

Basically I want to search by row, and I want to find Joan Williams, keep in mind that Joan is an element in the first column and Williams is an element is the second column

Should I use the "find" function? if yes how would it be written, else which function should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two demonstrative programs one for C++ 2003 and other for C++ 2011 that do the search

**C++ 2003**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

struct FindName : std::unary_function<bool, 
                                      const std::pair<std::string, std::string>>
{
    FindName( const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p ) : p( p ){} 
    bool operator ()( const std::vector<std::string> &v ) const
    {
        return v.size() > 1 && 
               v[0] == p.first && v[1] == p.second;
    }
protected:
    const std::pair<std::string, std::string> p;
};

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v;
    v.reserve( N );

    const char * initial[N][3] =
    {
        { "Joan", "Williams", "30" },
        { "Mike", "Williams", "40" },
        { "Joan", "Smith", "30" },
        { "William", "Anderson", "20" },
        { "Sara", "Jon", "33" }
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        v.push_back( std::vector<std::string>( initial[i], initial[i] + 3 ) );
    }

    std::pair<std::string, std::string> p( "Joan", "Williams" );

    typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::iterator iterator;

    iterator it = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), FindName( p ) );

    if ( it != v.end() )
    {
        for ( std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0; i < it->size(); ++i ) 
        {
            std::cout << ( *it )[i] << ' ';
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**C++ 2011**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v =
    {
        { "Joan", "Williams", "30" },
        { "Mike", "Williams", "40" },
        { "Joan", "Smith", "30" },
        { "William", "Anderson", "20" },
        { "Sara", "Jon", "33" }
    };

    std::pair<std::string, std::string> p( "Joan", "Williams" );

    auto it = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(),
                            [&]( const std::vector<std::string> &row )
                            {
                                return row.size() > 1 &&
                                       row[0] == p.first && row[1] == p.second;
                            } );

    if ( it != v.end() )
    {
        for ( const auto &s : *it ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The both programs' putput is

Joan Williams 30

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to use a data structure with an overloaded equality operator instead of `vector<string>` (especially since it seems like the third element should be saved in an integer, not a string).

Anyway, this is one possibility:

```
auto iter = std::find_if( std::begin(a_words), std::end(a_words),
                          [] (std::vector<std::string> const& vec)
                          { return vec[0] == "Joan" && vec[1] == "Williams";};
```

If the list is lexicographically sorted by the first or second column, a binary search can be used instead.

Comment: @user1804029 Well, ignore this answer then; It uses C++11. I assumed your compiler supported that, apparently it does not.

Comment: what if instead of typing Joan, I want to type a string variable that holds the value "Joan"? ofcourse the same goes for williams

Answer (score 0):

As of C++11, a range based for loop would be a simple and readable solution:

```
for(auto r: a_words)
    if(r[0] == "Joan" && r[1] == "Williams")
        cout << r[0] << " " << r[1] << " " << r[2] << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the answer of @Columbo is nice, eliminating C++ 11 features (besides initialization):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // Requires C++11
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> words = {
        { "Joan", "Williams",  "30" },
        { "Mike", "Williams", "40" },
        { "Joan", "Smith", "30" },
        { "William", "Anderson", "20" },
        { "Sara", "Jon", "33" },
    };

    // Below does not require C++11
    struct EqualName
    {
        const char* first;
        const char* second;
        EqualName(const char* first, const char* second)
        :   first(first), second(second)
        {}

        bool operator () (const std::vector<std::string>& element) {
            return element[0] == first && element[1] == second;
        }
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::const_iterator
    pos = std::find_if(words.begin(), words.end(), EqualName("Joan", "Smith"));
    if(pos != words.end())
        std::cout << (*pos)[0] << ' ' << (*pos)[1] << ' ' << (*pos)[2] << '\n';
}
```